# Within a subDocument _id appends at last of the document, why?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Using this schema

```
mongoose.Schema({
    world: String,
    color: [{ name: String }]
});
```

Gives me a document that has sub-documents containing `_id` fields.

```
{ _id: 'a9ec8475bf0d285e10ca8d42'
  world: 'matrix', 
  color: [
    { name: 'blue',  _id: '4a8c0e12135fa32e13db9ce9' },
    { name: 'red',   _id: '4a8c0a62254cd32e13db4ad8' },
    { name: 'white', _id: '4a8c04e2687ea32e13db1da7' }
]
```

**Why is the `_id` added/appended last in the case of the subdocument?**

Is there a way to keep `_id` first in the document?

Comment: Each color is an object, object keys are not ordered

Answer (score 0):

define color as a separate schema as below, then in the main schema put color of type colorSchema

```
var colorSchema= mongoose.Schema({
// your subschema content
}, { _id : false });
```

Comment: I don't want to remove _id.

I am much interested to know the fact why is _id added last in a subDocument where as _ids adds up as the first field in a normal document.

Comment: referencing to mongoose documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html Mongoose treats subdocuments as a normal document that must has its separate _id